# App Updates - Are they dependent on Google Market?

Tags: google-play-store, updates

I noticed on another android phone there were "updates" such as new Youtube, Gmail, etc. I never received a notification for these on my device. Are these delivered via Google Market, or is there another app I can use to update these other than Google Market?

Comment: What's the OS version of the phone that doesn't get updates?

Comment: It has Android 2.2.2

Comment: Do they show up in 'my apps' inside play store?

Comment: I don't have 'play store' app.

Comment: It's the android market. It was renamed.

Comment: Do you have a custom ROM?

Comment: No, is there a custom rom with an updater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App updates notification can come from the app themselves, but most commonly they come from the Play Store. Play Store will notify you for any updates to system apps (i.e. apps that originally comes with the phone) and apps that are installed through the Play Store; it won't notify you about updates to side-loaded apps our apps installed by third party market.

Third party market may also have their own update notification mechanism; which is completely unrelated to the Play Store update mechanism. They may or may not provide update to system apps, although most don't. Amazon App Market for example also provide updates notification. Note that update notification on third party market depends on the app developer updating the app on the third party market, some developers might update their app on Play but not on third party market or vice versa for various reasons.

Comment: Actually the sad thing is that the newest place store notifies you about updates for apps that you side loaded. What's even worse is that it links this app to your account and makes it impossible for you to actually buy it officially.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik: I thought they were a bug and had been fixed in the latest Play Market?

Comment: No it's definitely not fixed. I first noticed it in december (when the $.10 sale was running) when I wanted to buy an app that I previously got from Amazon. Basically if you ever pirated an app or "bought it" from an another store (amazon, getjar etc.) than you can't buy it from Google. It shows up as purchased even after you uninstalled it and even on the website. When you try to buy it says that you haven't purchased it, but after that it still shows up as purchased.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik: it should've already been fixed in Play 3.5, according to http://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Play-no-longer-shows-sideloaded-apps_id29035

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I was stuck on 3.4.7 None of the Android sites that I read mentioned this so I didn't update it manually.

Answer (score -2):

```
I noticed on another android phone there were "updates" such as new Youtube, Gmail, etc. I never received a notification for these on my device.
```

Go to Play Store App in your device and hit the Menu button and Go to My Apps you can see the installed apps list here. select any app and you can see the *Check box* `Allow Automatic updating` below the application screen shots. Check this and you will be notify every time when the updates are available and it will automatically update if you are connected with any Network (EDGE/Wi-Fi/3G).

```
Are these delivered via Google Market.
```

Ofcourse, they are delivered via Google Market.

```
or is there another app I can use to update these other than Google Market?
```

No, There are no other apps that you can use to update these apps. if there will be any app that offers updates they will ultimately redirected to the Google Market.

Comment: Allow automatic updates does not notify you, but updates the apps automatically.

Comment: As you can see the running updates in your Notification Bar.

Comment: That's a tad too late don't you think? Besides on ics these auto clear so you may even miss that an update happened.